# Android studio : Error : Module version com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.0 depends on libraries but is not a library itself

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I try to add this lib (https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) to my project. I added the compile library in my gradle file, but i get an error :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pp.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.2'
    compile 'com.iangclifton.android:floatlabel:1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.0.9@aar'
}
```

And i get this error :

```
Error:Module version com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.0 depends on libraries but is not a library itself
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this dependency:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.+'
```

You have to install the Android Support Library from the SDK, too.

Comment: I replaced compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+" by compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.+' and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: That's nice. Please note that v13 does not provide all classes of the v4 library. Therefore it is possible that you need to add both libraries in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with an oauth library. It was fixed after a while when, tired of implementing new changes to the build.gradle like changing the support libraries, I discarded the changes on the file (via Sourcetree). It synchronized and automatically got fixed.

(Android Studio) It's a kind of magic.